# definition was declared but never used in document error while creating yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, swagger

I am very much new using YAML. I have already created a yaml file. I added new property in it and I am getting a warning in swagger editor saying "definition was declared but never used in document".
Why this warning only to the newly added field other fields are not showing this warning?
This is the field I added:

```
eligibleSpeed:
title: "eligibleSpeed"
type: object
properties:
access:
$ref: '#/components/schemas/AccessReference'
MaxSpeed:
$ref: '#/components/schemas/Speed'
```

Can anyone help me on this???

Comment: You cannot have two `$ref` keys in the same YAML mapping, that's invalid. You probably want to indent those.